# How add To-do lists feature to CKEditor 5 in react application?

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor

I have a simple ClassicEditor config in my app, and it's working fine, but I also want to add some extra plugins like todo-list
[enter link description here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/todo-lists.html)

And I have trouble doing this.
How correctly add todo-list feature or some other using React and CKEditor 5?

When I try to import TodoList feature from ckeditor I get the next error

```
Uncaught CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules
```

My code:

```
    import { CKEditor } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";
    import TodoList from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list/src/todolist';
    import ClassicEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic";
    
    export default function ScriptTextSection({ script, dispatch }) {
    
      const onChangeScript = (script) => {
        return dispatch(scriptTextFieldUpdateAction({ script }));
      };
    
      return (
        <div className="script_section">
          <CKEditor
            editor={ClassicEditor}
            data={script}
            config={{
              toolbar: [
                "heading",
                "|",
                "bold",
                "italic",
                "link",
                "bulletedList",
                "numberedList",
                "blockQuote",
                "|",
                "undo",
                "redo",
                "todoList"
              ],
             plugins: [TodoList]
            }}
            onReady={(editor) => {}}
            onChange={(event, editor) => {
              const data = editor.getData();
              return onChangeScript(data);
            }}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the installation section on the Todo List link you provided, there is a link to dedicated page related to [installing plugins](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/getting-started/installing-plugins.html). You can't just add additional plugin to the imported CKEditor. You need to either [add a plugin to the build](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/getting-started/installing-plugins.html#adding-a-plugin-to-a-build) which you'll later include in your project, or [add a plugin to the editor](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/getting-started/installing-plugins.html#adding-a-plugin-to-an-editor) and rebuild it.

I am not adding the code here as someone may just copy paste it and not read the full steps required to make it work.